# How do I change a file's attribute using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that copies files from one location to another.  Once the copy is complete I want to clear the Archive attribute on the files in the source location that have been copied.

How do I clear the Archive attribute of a file using Powershell?

Comment: This might also help: http://cmschill.net/stringtheory/2008/04/bitwise-operators/ **Edit**: Possible answer from archive.org now that the link is returning a 404:
https://web.archive.org/web/20100105052819/http://cmschill.net/stringtheory/2008/04/bitwise-operators/.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [here](http://scriptolog.blogspot.com/2007/10/file-attributes-helper-functions.html):

```
function Get-FileAttribute{
    param($file,$attribute)
    $val = [System.IO.FileAttributes]$attribute;
    if((gci $file -force).Attributes -band $val -eq $val){$true;} else { $false; }
} 


function Set-FileAttribute{
    param($file,$attribute)
    $file =(gci $file -force);
    $file.Attributes = $file.Attributes -bor ([System.IO.FileAttributes]$attribute).value__;
    if($?){$true;} else {$false;}
}
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use the good old dos attrib command like this:

```
attrib -a *.*
```

Or to do it using Powershell you can do something like this:

```
$a = get-item myfile.txt
$a.attributes = 'Normal'
```

Answer (score 18):

As the Attributes is basically a bitmask field, you need to be sure clear the archive field while leaving the rest alone:

```
PS C:\> $f = get-item C:\Archives.pst
PS C:\> $f.Attributes
Archive, NotContentIndexed
PS C:\> $f.Attributes = $f.Attributes -band (-bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive)
PS C:\> $f.Attributes
NotContentIndexed
PS H:\>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$attr = [System.IO.FileAttributes]$attrString
$prop = Get-ItemProperty -Path $pathString
# SetAttr
$prop.Attributes = $prop.Attributes -bor $attr
# ToggleAttr
$prop.Attributes = $prop.Attributes -bxor $attr
# HasAttr
$hasAttr = ($prop.Attributes -band $attr) -eq $attr
# ClearAttr
if ($hasAttr) {$prop.Attributes = $prop.Attributes -bxor $attr }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following command to toggle the behaviour

```
$file = (gci e:\temp\test.txt)
$file.attributes
Archive

$file.attributes = $file.Attributes -bxor ([System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive)
$file.attributes
Normal

$file.attributes = $file.Attributes -bxor ([System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive)
$file.attributes
Archive
```

Answer (score 2):

Mitch's answer works well for most attributes, but [will not work](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2012/03/20/powershell-dir-command-tricks.aspx) for "Compressed." If you want to set the compressed attribute on a folder using PowerShell you have to use the command-line tool [compact](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976811.aspx)

```
compact /C /S c:\MyDirectory
```

Comment: Well of course you can't arbitrarily set the `Compressed` attribute on a file *that is not compressed*.

Comment: @IanKemp - why "of course"? If I'm presented a list of things that I can read the state of and change, then there's no way to arbitrarily know "except for that one".

Now, looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes you can see  "It is not possible to change the compression status of a File object by using the File.SetAttributes method. Instead, you must actually compress the file using either a compression tool or one of the classes in the System.IO.Compression namespace."

Answer (score 2):

```
# Show attributes
$file.Attributes

# Set (overwriting existing) attributes:
$file.Attributes = 'Archive, Readonly'

# Add (retaining existing) attributes:
$file.Attributes += 'Archive, Readonly'

# Remove specific attributes:
$file.Attributes -= 'Archive, Readonly'

# Check for specific attributes:
$file.Attributes.hasflag([IO.FileAttributes]'Archive, Readonly')

# Forget about bitwise operators ;-)
```

Comment: All command lines work fine except the one with +=. I have the following error: InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileAttributes] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'

Comment: @Luke I use Powershell 7. Maybe you have an older version.

Answer (score -1):

I found Simon Steele's answer to be helpful, though I needed to modify more than just one file so I changed it to the following:

```
$BadAttributes = Get-ChildItem "C:\PATH" -Recurse -Force

foreach($File in $BadAttributes) {

if (Test-Path -Path $File -IsValid)
{

$File.attributes = 'Normal'

}

}

# Check file attributes
Get-ItemProperty -Path "C:\PATH" | Format-list -Property Attributes -Force
```