# Script to compare existence of files from one folder to another where archive flag is true (file attributes O)

Tags: powershell

I am constructing a powershell script to query the existence of archived files within the folder that the files are archived to.

EMC's disk extender moves the file from the live storage to archive storage and leaves a stub/link to the file.

You can still list the archive stub in the directory tree and the file still appears to be the same size but in reality it is an archive stub probably 1k in size.

The file attribute(s) of an archive stub give the value O

I need to query the files in the live folder where attribute of the file = O

then compare the list to my archive directory on another server outputting the files that do not exist on my archive where an archive stub exists on the live storage.

basically I need to know how to query the file attribute to retrieve O and do a compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464777/how-do-i-change-a-files-attribute-using-powershell)) will return either true or false, depending on your O attribute

```
function Get-FileAttribute{
param($file,$attribute)
$val = [System.IO.FileAttributes]$attribute;
if((gci $file -force).Attributes -band $val -eq $val){$true;} else { $false; }
} 

Get-FileAttribute "C:\PST\T.dll" "Offline"
```

You can use something like this:

```
function Get-FileAttribute{
param($file,$attribute)
$val = [System.IO.FileAttributes]$attribute;
if((gci $file -force).Attributes -band $val -eq $val){$true;} else { $false; }
} 

# Get items both from folder and from archive
$folder = "C:\pst"
$archive = "C:\pst"
$itemsFromFolder = get-childitem $folder -recurse
$itemsFromArchive = get-childitem $archive -recurse

# Filter items from folder to have only offline files
$offlineItemsFromFolder = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.IO.FileInfo]'
foreach($item in $itemsFromFolder)
{
$isOffline = Get-FileAttribute $item.FullName  "Offline"
if ($isOffline)
{
    $offlineItemsFromFolder.Add($item)
}
}

# Compare each offline item from folder with item from archive
foreach($item in $offlineItemsFromFolder)
{
    $result = $itemsFromArchive | Where-Object {$_.FullName -eq $item.FullName.Replace($folder, $archive)}
# Do some processing depending on $result being $true or $false
}
```